# Ajax post gives error: was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, ajax, ssl, https

I have a form which posts data using ajax. However this gives me an error:

```
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

But all content is served over HTTPS for as far as I can see. This is my code:

```
$('#webinarform').submit(function(){
        var $form = $(this),
         $error = $form.find('.error-container'),
         action  = $form.attr('action');

         $error.slideUp(750, function() {
         $error.hide();

         var $name = $form.find('.form-control-name'),
            $email = $form.find('.form-control-email'),
            $seminar = $form.find('.form-control-seminar'),
            $message = $form.find('.form-control-message');

         $.post(action, {
                 name: $name.val(),
                 email: $email.val(),
                 seminar: $seminar.val(),
                 message: $message.val(),
            },
            function(data){
                 $error.html(data);
                 $error.slideDown('slow');
                 if (data.match('success') != null) {
                    $name.val('');
                    $email.val('');
                    $seminar.val('');
                    $message.val('');
                 }
            }
         );

        });

        return false;

    });
```

My html:

```
<form class="form contact-form" id="webinarform" autocomplete="off" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="mail/mail_send.php">
   <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <h4 class="font-alt h3bold">Meld je aan voor de webinar</h4>
         <div class="error-container"></div>
         <!-- Name -->
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="seminar" class="form-control-seminar" value="<?PHP echo $_GET['seminar']; ?>">
            <input style="text-transform:none;" type="text" name="name" class="input-md form-control-name round form-control" placeholder="Naam" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
         </div>
         <!-- Email -->
         <div class="form-group">
            <input style="text-transform:none;" type="email" name="email" class="input-md round form-control-email form-control" placeholder="Email" pattern=".{5,100}" required>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <!-- Message -->
         <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="message" class="input-md round form-control-message form-control" style="height: 178px;text-transform:none!important;" placeholder="Opmerking"></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="cf-left-col">
         <!-- Inform Tip -->
         <div class="form-tip pt-20">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> E-mailadres en naam zijn verplicht
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cf-right-col">
         <!-- Send Button -->
         <div class="align-right pt-10">
            <button class="submit_btn btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round">Verstuur</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

It ends up at my javascript when I submit the form but stops there and throws me this error in my console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysite.nl/seminarcontact.php?seminar=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://mysite.nl/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Nowhere in my code do I see `http`. So I am not sure why it is giving me this error. My entire website is `https`.

What's going on?

Comment: does your server redirect some requests perhaps? with absolutely no information about your http server, it's just speculation

Comment: Is your site set to be https in the *.htaccess* file? Have you checked all the places that has some url logic in terms of what you are doing, and made sure that none of them are making http requests over a https connection? In the example you provided here, I don't see any notable *"stuff"* (for lack of better word), that could cause the issue.